# If is nothing statement not checking for empty space

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I just enabled 'Option Strict' and on the advice of the popup message it advised me to change my statement. Previously, the statement was as in code below. It advised me to change = "" to Is Nothing. However, this is not displaying the message 'No email on record' statement. Have I coded this correctly.

Being new to vb.net I need some expert advice. Thanks

Original code

```
If Email = "" Then
    txtEmail.Text = "No email on record" ' blank if dbnull values
    txtEmail.ForeColor = Color.Red
Else
    txtEmail.Text = CType(Email, String)
    txtEmail.ForeColor = Color.Black
End If
```

Revised code

```
If Email Is Nothing Then
    txtEmail.Text = "No email on record" ' blank if dbnull values
    txtEmail.ForeColor = Color.Red
Else
    txtEmail.Text = CType(Email, String)
    txtEmail.ForeColor = Color.Black
End If
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Email) Then
```

[String.IsNullOrEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx) checks for both Nothing and Empty string.

Comment: I used If String.IsNullOrEmpty(CStr(Email)) Then and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You should use [String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) method, it indicates whether a specified string is Nothing, empty, or consists only of white-space characters.

Try,

```
 If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Email) Then
```